# FLEX - Opening Tree branches..?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, adobe

I've been using this code to help with navigation in my tree component, but I do have one problem.

If I click on a "folder", or branch, (at the name listed) it opens up fine, and closes other open folders/branches that has the same parent.

BUT, if I click on the little arrow in front I get an error.

```
<mx:Tree id="treeView" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"
                             itemRenderer="components.CustomTreeItemRenderer"
                             paddingBottom="2" showRoot="true"
                             itemClick="treeItemClick(event)"
                             itemOpen="treeItemOpen(event)" />

        public function treeItemOpen(event:Event):void {
            var a:Array=openParent(event.currentTarget.selectedItem, [event.currentTarget.selectedItem]);
            if(a) treeView.openItems = a;
        }

        public function openParent(o:Object,a:Array):Array{
            if( o.parent()){
                a.push(o.parent());
                a=openParent(o.parent(),a);
            }
            return a;
        }
```

This is the error message I get:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at Test_tree_001/openParent()[D:\Flash Builder - Workspace\vCog Workspace\vCog Flash 14-12-2011 - SWF\src\Test_tree_001.mxml:212]
at Test_tree_001/treeItemOpen()[D:\Flash Builder - Workspace\vCog Workspace\vCog Flash 14-12-2011 - SWF\src\Test_tree_001.mxml:207]
at Test_tree_001/__treeView_itemOpen()[D:\Flash Builder - Workspace\vCog Workspace\vCog Flash 14-12-2011 - SWF\src\Test_tree_001.mxml:705]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at mx.core::UIComponent/dispatchEvent()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:13128]
at mx.controls::Tree/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::dispatchTreeEvent()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\mx\src\mx\controls\Tree.as:3551]
at mx.controls::Tree/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::onTweenEnd()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\mx\src\mx\controls\Tree.as:2381]
at mx.effects::Tween/endTween()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\effects\Tween.as:566]
at mx.effects::Tween/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::doInterval()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\effects\Tween.as:607]
at mx.effects::Tween$/timerHandler()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\effects\Tween.as:191]
at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
```

### EDIT

I have this code too, which opens up the branch if I click the text.
Somehow I still get errors with the new code.

```
if (treeView.dataDescriptor.isBranch(selectedItem)){  
                trace("isBranch: Triggered in treeItemClick!");
                treeView.expandItem(selectedItem,!treeView.isItemOpen(selectedItem),false,true);
                }
```

This is the error I'm getting with the new code:

```
TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
at Test_tree_001/treeItemClick()[D:\Flash Builder - Workspace\vCog Workspace\vCog Flash 14-12-2011 - SWF\src\Test_tree_001.mxml:411]
at Test_tree_001/__treeView_itemClick()[D:\Flash Builder - Workspace\vCog Workspace\vCog Flash 14-12-2011 - SWF\src\Test_tree_001.mxml:734]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at mx.core::UIComponent/dispatchEvent()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:13128]
at mx.controls.listClasses::ListBase/mouseClickHandler()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\mx\src\mx\controls\listClasses\ListBase.as:10328]
at mx.controls::Tree/mouseClickHandler()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\mx\src\mx\controls\Tree.as:3129]
```

Comment: Updated post with error message.. Line 212 is the if(o.parent) line

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error message because the Object `o` that's getting passed to the `openParent` method is null. Because there's no valid object getting passed Flex can't evaluate the `parent` property.

My best guess is because when clicking on the arrow there is no `selectedItem` so `event.currentTarget.selectedItem` will always be `null`. You'll have to find another way of identifying which node was selected.

I did some quick Googling and found [this article](http://blog.lyraspace.com/2009/03/31/how-to-automatically-close-open-branches-of-a-flex-tree-control/). The last comment in that article mentioned:

> This code didn’t work for me because I don’t want to open/close items
>   if I click them, i want them to open/close if I click the plus/minus.
>   The code that did work for me:

```
protected function tree_itemOpenHandler(event:TreeEvent):void { 
  tree.openItems =[event.item,event.item.parent(),event.item.parent().parent(), event.item.parent().parent().parent()]; 
}
```

> This handles trees that go 3 levels deep, if you for example have a
>   tree with 4 levels, you have to add another:
>   `event.item.parent().parent().parent().parent()`

Hopefully this helps get you started in the right direction.

Comment: Updated my post. Still got some problems. I might just take away the code that opens and closes the branches when I click the text (and not the arrow). The best would be to have both working..
Also, how do I scroll to the opened position? As of now, when I click a branch, it scrolls back up to the top, and it's a bit annoying. Thanks! :)

Comment: I'll try whats suggested in the article you posted.

Comment: Tried following this example too, but doesn't seem to work.. Strange...
http://blog.lyraspace.com/2009/04/02/slick-flex-tree-control/

Comment: @Stian What's not working? Are you getting the same error message as before or a different one?

Comment: I think the problem is that I need to be able to click the text (not just the arrow) to open/close a branch. But at the same time, when I do open a branch, all other branches inside the same parent should be closed, except for the newly opened of course.

I've probably got some conflict here, but I'll post an update later today